# Select text just like "Ctrl+A" when clicking the text?

Tags: javascript, html, range

I want to select the text in a paragraph when I click or double click the `<p>` tag. Not highlight, just like using mouse to make a select area to choose text to be selected!

I have several paragraph and *.rar file link addresses on the page, and I want to select all the text when I click on one of them. I think the textbox could work that way but I like it to be in a paragraph or link tag.

Is there a way to select all text in paragraph by clicking another element?

Comment: Ummm, a little more information please

Comment: This needs more context. Are you asking about a text editor? a WinForms App? A web app? An iPhone app? An Android App?

Comment: From the sounds of it: you want to be able to select paragraph text. You can already do that. (Wow, that got solved quickly.) But seriously, give us more information.

Comment: Should we tag this as HTML? *"click the "p" tag"* sounds like it's HTML related.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a function that will select the contents of the element you pass to it:

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
    var range;
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.body && document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById("your_para_id");
    selectElementContents(el);
};
```

Comment: Perfect! I thought it was the alternative way to get my target.Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about JavaScript, look at [*Introduction to Range*](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) by Peter-Paul Koch (famous for his compatibility tables).

Comment: I am so sorry! It is about a web page function.I have several paragraph on the page, and I want to select all the text when I click on one of them.

Comment: I had tried using text box to hold the file link address,when I focus and select the text in the textbox.The flashgot work well.But when I de-select the text box,flashgot remain holding the file link address!

Comment: range.selectNodeContents is undefined.. in chrome

Answer (score 0):

You CAN select a whole paragraph with a double click. Why do you want to change that?

Comment: Yeah.I am so stupid.But is it a way to select the paragraph text by click another element ,such as the title "h" tag!?