# Check if any formatting have been given in a Page

Tags: javascript

While searching text in a document

```
window.find(t)
```

Will highlight the text in document. But how can I highlight all the text in a web page. That means how can I highlight all the text in web page as giving complete design mode text as input to the window.find()

The original intention behind this is using the trick provided by Tim Down in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445518/how-to-check-whether-a-text-is-having-bold-in-a-web-page/9445554#comment11946894_9445554) page I want to check whether any formatting have been given in the document.
Please let me know if you need any other input to be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
window.find(document.body.innerText)
```

or

```
function selectElementContents(el) {
    var range;
    if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        range = document.createRange();
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (document.body && document.body.createTextRange) {
        range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(el);
        range.select();
    }
}
selectElementContents(document.body)
```

Comment: [That looks familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4012886/96100) :) The `innerText` trick won't work in browsers that don't support `innerText` (e.g. Firefox) and may not work in other browsers either, depending on the document, so I'd lose that bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the text in the document's body, you would use `document.body.innerText`. If you want all the HTML in the document's body, you would use `document.body.innerHTML`.